# How to add search box to DOJO mobile heading?

Tags: dojo, dojox.mobile

Is there any way to add a search text box to dojox/mobile/heading(like the standard search box in IOS e.g)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just put the SearchBox inside the heading if you're define a heading like

```
<div>
```

and not like header.

```
<div data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Heading"
        data-dojo-props="label:'Label'">
            <input id="searchBox" data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.SearchBox"
                data-dojo-props="type:'search'" type="search"
                placeholder="Placeholder..."
                style="position: absolute; margin-right: 6px; right: 0px; top: 15%; width: 30%;">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

dojo mobile 1.9 provides a new mixin, FilteredListMixin, that you can use for this purpose. You can find reference to it in the api documentation (http://dojotoolkit.org/api/, select version 1.9 in the left column and then select dojox/mobile/FilteredListMixin in the tree).